# Can't see a custom font in Interface Builder

Tags: fonts, interface-builder, xcode7, truetype

So I've downloaded a free TTF font and installed it on my Mac by dragging the files to Font Book. I've also added the files to my Xcode project, ensured they're added to the build targets, and listed the file names in Info.plist.

At this point I'd expect the be able to select that font in the IB. But it's not there. I verified that the font is installed on the system by opening TextEdit and checking the font list there.

I'd much prefer not to have to set the fonts in code everywhere. Any advice how I can make the font appear in IB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I failed to correctly add the .ttf files to the project. I've dragged them into the project, but the file names were showing in red in the Project Explorer. After I dragged them again, this time to the Supporting Files folder, things started working correctly.